# What does "FunctionName(bool() args)" mean in C#?

Tags: c#, syntax

Can someone tell me what `FunctionName(bool() args)` means in C#?

Answer (score 7):

That is invalid syntax in C#.

You probably meant `FunctionName(bool[] args)` (`[]` instead of `()`), which means a [function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx) that takes an [array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453.aspx) of [booleans](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8f5xwh7.aspx) called `args` as a [parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx).

Note that it's missing a return type, so it should probably be **`void`**`FunctionName(bool[] args)` (or some other type instead of `void`)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't mean anything!

Are you sure that the `bool()` part is meant to contain parentheses and not square brackets?

If it was declared with square brackets as `FunctionName(bool[] args)` then that would mean that there's a method called `FunctionName` which takes a single argument called `args`, and that argument must be an array of `bool` values.

If this is meant to be a method declaration then it would also need a return type. For example, `string FunctionName(bool[] args)` or `void FunctionName(bool[] args)` etc.

Comment: doesn't that need the `params`keyword?